# Use python with mobaxterm to copy 25 random files from one folder to another

Tags: python, linux, ssh, mobaxterm

I'm trying to write a python script that I can run using mobaxterm to grab 25 random files from a folder and copy them to another folder.

I am very new to using mobaxterm, my internship has been mostly writing small scripts to help my coworkers automate daily stuff, so any advice is appreciated! I can open mobaxterm and navigate to the folder where this python script is held but I get these errors:

```
IOError: [Errno 21] Is a directory:
```

my code right now is as follows

```
import shutil, random, os

dirpath = '/SSH_folder_where_stuff_is/images/' 

destDirectory = '/SSH_folder_where_stuff_should_go/'

filenames = random.sample(os.listdir(dirpath), 25)
for fname in filenames:
    srcpath = os.path.join(dirpath, fname)
    shutil.copyfile(srcpath, destDirectory)
    print('done!')
```

Thank you in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: How are you running the script?  It looks like it's trying to run it through `bash` and not `python`.  You may want to add a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) to the top of the script.

Comment: @0x5453 hi there! I am running it by calling python then the filepath, you were right about it originally running bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your `shutil` usage. `shutil` takes two filenames, but in your code the second one is a directory.

Here is a corrected version.

```py
import shutil, random, os

dirpath = '/SSH_folder_where_stuff_is/images/' 
destDirectory = '/SSH_folder_where_stuff_should_go/'

filenames = random.sample(os.listdir(dirpath), 5)
for fname in filenames:
    srcpath = os.path.join(dirpath, fname)
    # Change the second parameter here.
    shutil.copyfile(srcpath, destDirectory+fname)
    print('done!')
```

Comment: I feel very silly for not realizing that is the issue, thank you very very much!